# How can I query the version number of a remote rsync server (daemon)?

Tags: backup, rsync, network-attached-storage, remote

How can I query the version number of a remote rsync server (or daemon)?

I can find out the version number of my local rsync client using `--version`:

```
% rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2022 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: https://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
...[details elided]...
rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. ...Licence for details.
```

But sending `--version` to the remote server does not appear to have any effect, even if I ask the remote server to be verbose:

```
% rsync -nvv -M--version -M-vvv myserver.local::
opening tcp connection to myserver.local port 873
sending daemon args: --server --sender -vvnde.LsfxCIvu --version -vvv . /  (7 args)
my_share1       
my_share2           
...[details elided]...
my_sharex
```

The context: `myserver.local` is a Network-Attached Storage (NAS) server with a limited Linux OS. It's purpose is to back up another, primary server. It came with rsync 3.0.7, but I installed rsync 3.2.7 (via the Entware package manager, if I recall correctly). I had to do some boot script trickery to make the newer rsync run in preference to the older one. I think I got it right, but I would like to confirm. I want to be sure that, when my primary server contacts `myserver.local`, that the version of rsync which answers is in fact the newer version.

Related but separate question: from the `myserver.local` shell, logged in as root, how can I interrogate the version number of the `rsync` daemon which I can see running via ps?

```
# ps | grep rsync
12682 admin        88 S   rsync --daemon --config=/etc/rsyncd.conf
```

(I should perhaps move this into its own question.)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know of a built-in way to determine the version of a remote rsyncd daemon, you can get an idea by telnetting into port 873 to view its response. It will greet you with the protocol version it supports.

```
telnet myserver.local 873
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myserver.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
@RSYNCD: 31.0 sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 md4
```

This is the response for rsyncd **3.1.3**.

**rsync 3.0.7** should be using protocol **26**.

**rsync 3.2.7** should be using protocol **32**.

For your last question about the running daemon version, one way is to figure out the full path to the binary, then run it with `--version`. You can do so by looking at the /proc filesystem like so (example for php):

```
$ ps ax | grep php
 1995 ?        Ss     5:20 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
$ ls -l /proc/1995/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 11 07:09 /proc/1995/exe -> /usr/sbin/php-fpm8.1
```